# Flask Application : add condition to check for environment in html template file

Tags: python, html, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jinja2

I am rendering an application in an `<iframe>` in my Flask Application.

The localhost link is `http://localhost:8000/dashboard2/` and pushing this to `AWS Elastic Beanstalk` hosted on: `http://server-name.elasticbeanstalk.com/dashboard2`

My application is written in python and `dashboard.html` jinja template renders the application.

Contents of `dashboard.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

  <iframe loading="lazy" class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://localhost:8000/dashboard/" width="100%" height="600"></iframe>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Questions is, how can I check for environment type `os` and render either app on `localhost` or `production`? I'd need to do this in `.html` template.

Is there a way to access and print the environment in jinja template?

Answer (score 4):

I would set an environment variable when running the app that specifies whether the app should be run in `development` or `production` mode:

```
FLASK_ENV=production flask run
```

Then inside your template file you can access the environment through the app's `config` and render different content based on the value:

```
<div>
  {% if config["ENV"] == 'production' %}
    Production content...
  {% else %}
    Development content...
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: For production, I don't "run" the app, it's deployed on the environment. I'd need this condition in the script somewhere.

Comment: @kms That distinction is not important. As long as the environment variable is set somehow, this approach works. I'm not too familiar elasticbeanstalk, but I found this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html.

Comment: I see. I guess what I mean is I cannot set the environment at runtime / when running the application on production. So, I'd need to set it in the script somewhere and check for it in jinja template.